# quick transpose 3D matrice in opencv

Tags: opencv, matrix

I have created a 3D matrix in opencv with the size: 120x100x50 :

```
int _sz[] = {120,100,50};
Mat src(3,_sz,CV_32FC1,Scalar(2));
```

I want to transpose the first and the second dimension of this matrix to 100x120x50.
I use 3 loop iteration to manually transpose

```
for ()
    for ()
    for ()
           dst.at<float>( , , ) = src.at<float>( , , );
```

But it takes too long with this way. And, I cannot utilize channel as the third dimension because the third dimension is 50 whereas OpenCV mat only supports 4 channels in maximum. Are there any other way to do this work quicker? Just do something like OpenCV did with multichannel matrix because when I test with matrix 120x100x4 by using 4 channel as the third dimension, the execution time is much better.

Comment: If this is actually your code, it will not work. Declaring the `Mat` as `CV_8UC1` indicates `uchar` element types, while you access them as `float`.

Comment: I am sorry, it is because I tested with new application and using .at<int>(), instead. I already edited it.

Comment: And of course, my 3D matrix has different values, Scalar(2) for all values is just an example, so plz do not use something like reshape() function in opencv (cannot use reshape function directly for a 3D matrix).

Comment: Depending on your definition of "too long", there might not be a way around this (I'm trying to think of one, though). For each element you transpose, you will be copying *50 float values*. In total, you'll be shuffling around over 2MB of data each time you do the transposition.

Comment: When I use the above way, it takes more than 300ms; but when I change to use .ptr[], it only takes about 7-8ms. However, it is really a large data in anyway. How many MB of data will make the app halted?

Comment: Is using `ptr()` fast enough for your purposes? If it is, you can post that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Yes, it is fast enough. I have already solved this prob by changing code from getting array in structure to get array directly. But now the time still doesn't satisfy. The multiplication operator with a large-size matrices in opencv still takes too long compare to Matlab operator.

Answer (score 0):

I change to access values of matrix like array values. Execution time is much better. But it still accesses one-by-one, not copy block-by-block.

```
int indexOrder[3];
int order[3]={1,0,2};
int* _srcSize = srcMat.size.p;
int srcMatSize[] = {_srcSize[0],_srcSize[1],_srcSize[2]};
int dstMatSize[] = {srcMatSize[order[0]], srcMatSize[order[1]], srcMatSize[order[2]]}; 
Mat dstMat(3, dstMatSize, CV_32FC1);
float* srcArr, *dstArr;
srcArr = srcMat.ptr<float>();
dstArr = dstMat.ptr<float>();

for (indexOrder[0]=0;indexOrder[0]<srcMatSize[0];indexOrder[0]++)
  for (indexOrder[1]=0;indexOrder[1]<srcMatSize[1];indexOrder[1]++)
    for (indexOrder[2]=0;indexOrder[2]<srcMatSize[2];indexOrder[2]++)               
        dstArr[indexOrder[order[0]]*dstMatSize[1] + indexOrder[order[1]]*dstMatSize[2] + indexOrder[order[2]]] = 
                    srcArr[indexOrder[0]*srcMatSize[1]+indexOrder[1]*srcMatSize[2]+indexOrder[2]];
```